# Производительность Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, plsql, dba

Исходные данные: Oracle 18XE, который крутится на линуксовом сервере. Больше на серваке ничего нет. В качестве фронта - Oracle APEX 19й версии. Всего около сотни пользователей. Около 20 +/- 5 онлайн.

Периодически, случайным образом подскакивает нагрузка на проц и память. Иногда база в этот момент выдает ошибку 503 с текстом "ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database... All connections in the universal connection pool are in use". Иногда просто "Service unavailable"

Без лицензии нет доступа к отчетам.
Есть какие-нибудь способы вычислить зловреда? Логи, хитрые хаки? Куда можно посмотреть?
Подозрение падает на неоптимизированный запрос, который время от времени запускают юзеры.

DBA у нас, к сожалению, отсутствует.

Comment: Можно на уровне ОС посмотреть, какой серверный процес потребляет немеренно ресурсы и с его pid в БД посмотреть, что он в данный момент делает.  Вообще, неоптимизированный запрос будет просто долго работать, но он не "посадит" всю систему. У вас, возможно, проблема с БД и не связана.

Answer (score 0):

Предположительно, проблема была в том, что множество запросов от пользователей формировали очередь на выполнение, а диск не успевал их вовремя отрабатывать из-за чего случались временные простои. Мы оптимизировали запросы на самых тяжелых страницах и переехали на более быстрый рэйд. С тех пор проблема не появлялась